# AngularJS JSON Check Object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am currently using Angular to read in a json file and output it onto a table.

Because some of the objects are a little different, I want to make a check to see if job.text exists.

```
[
  {
    "job": {
      "href": "www.google.com",
      "text": "Google"
    },
    "api": "Some Text Here"
  },
  {
    "job": "Yahoo",
    "api": "More text here"
  }
]
```

If job.text exists, then display job.text
else display job

Here is my html from angular but only displaying objects with job.text, otherwise it returns nothing.Is there a simple way to write a check statement to make sure I can display both types of objects?

```
<td><a ng-href="{{item.job.href}}" target="_blank">{{item.job.text}}</a></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ternary:

```
{{item.job.text ? item.job.text : item.job}}
```

You should try and normalize your data struct a bit - seems odd that `job` may contain an object or a simple text field.